# I need to get rid of the highlighting happening in my build.gradle file Android Studio. How do I do this?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, syntax-highlighting

The libraries I have mentioned in my Android Studio build.gradle file are getting highlighted and I do not know how to undo this. It is probably because of some plugins I have used in Android Studio but I can't figure out which one. How do I get rid of this highlighting? Clicking on it temporarily removes it but I need a permanent solution.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: check your plugins and remove all the unnecessary ones

Comment: I did that actually but it's still happening

Comment: reinstall Android Studio. That should remove all plugins.

Comment: That's not an option right now. I have a lot of ongoing projects. This issue is not that serious but I would love a solution.

Comment: what it says when you hover over the highlighted dependencies ?

Comment: It just gives a popup displaying the same line without the highlight